# How to count the number of changed or added lines in an SVN branch?

Tags: svn

I would like to add up the number of line changes in an SVN branch so I can tell how far I have gone during a project from another side and estimate the probability of conflict when I merge it with trunk.

The way I can think of is to grab the unified diff and do some grep|wc -l hacks, but the problem is it's hard to separate different file types, for example, front-end source files (.css, .html) and back-end source files(.xml, .java)

Comment: There is a much better way to get a feel for possible conflicts: `--dry-run` option.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cosidering beginRev as the initial revision of the changeset you want to measure and endRev as the final revision:

```
svn diff --summarize -rbeginRev:endRev <URLtoBranch>
```

This will give you the output of files added, deleted and modified.

I you want more detail level you could parse the svn diff output through `diffstat`:

```
svn diff -rbeginRev:endRev <URLtoBranch> | diffstat
```

This will return an histogram of the changes with information for each file, and a summary of files changed, lines added and deleted.

Comment: I don't know if it is clear from Diego's example but when I tried this, I needed use the local URL as not the url to the remote repository.

Answer (score 3):

[StatSVN](http://statsvn.org/) might be what you are looking for. I used it a while back briefly and it seemed good for giving developers feedback. I'm not sure if it will give you exactly what you need but it might be worth a quick look.