# Tortoise SVN - Check only NEW added files from a period of time

Tags: sqlite, svn, tortoisesvn

I wonder if there's a SIMPLE way in Tortoise SVN fucntions or by using SQLLite to check how many NEW added files to the repository were added and which during a minor or great period of time?

EX: New added files since Jan 1, 2022 to October 10, 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`svn log --verbose`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/log/) command that should work faster than `svn diff`. Here is an example:

```
svn log --verbose -r {2022-01-01}:{2022-10-10} https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/asf
```

---

You can also parse the output of [`svn diff --summarize`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/diff/) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11016180/761095). `A` stands for added files, so you can count the number of lines that begin with `A`. Here is an example:

```
svn diff --summarize -r1750000:1800000 https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/asf
```

or with dates instead of revision numbers

```
svn diff --summarize -r {2022-01-01}:{2022-10-10} https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/asf
```

If you use the [`--xml`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.xml) option, you can check for `item=added` as in this output:

```
<path
   item="added"
   props="none"
   kind="file">https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/asf/cassandra/site/publish/css/style.css</path>
```